# CSS box-shadow on round image

Tags: css

I tried to put an fade out effect on a picture. I used box-shadow (inset). There is a slim circle (in my browser at least (ff, chrome on MacOS)) where the box shadow started. Any tricks to hide this thin outer circle? I tried to use an `img` element in the `div` and put a box shadow over the div, but failed.

```css
div {
    background-image: url('https://www.welt.de/img/wirtschaft/mobile172774245/5812507447-ci102l-w1024/GERMANY-US-GABRIEL-MUSK-TESLA.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 25px 25px #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could make a wrapper and give it overflow: hidden so that it cuts the thin circle off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible workaround: make background clip to the content box and set a minimal padding. Here's an example:

```css
div {
    background-image: url('https://www.welt.de/img/wirtschaft/mobile172774245/5812507447-ci102l-w1024/GERMANY-US-GABRIEL-MUSK-TESLA.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 25px 25px #fff;
    background-clip: content-box;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably the best solution so far

Answer (score 3):

More workaround: ditch inset shadow and use radial gradient background instead:

```css
div {
    background-image: radial-gradient(closest-side, transparent, transparent 80%, white), url('https://www.welt.de/img/wirtschaft/mobile172774245/5812507447-ci102l-w1024/GERMANY-US-GABRIEL-MUSK-TESLA.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 50%;
 }
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't like this solution, but I propose it as workaround:

```css
div {
    background-image: url('https://www.welt.de/img/wirtschaft/mobile172774245/5812507447-ci102l-w1024/GERMANY-US-GABRIEL-MUSK-TESLA.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 25px 25px #fff;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  border: solid 10px white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```